# how to check messages exists

Tags: 8, theming, status-messages

I want to check is there any messages in my template 
in drupal 7 there was a global variable in page template variables [messages](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7.x)

now in drupal 8 I want to check  is there any message  but `messages` variable in `page--front.html.twig` is always empty, alternative way is check  region highlightes( because  status messages block is in highlighted region) 
**but below  statement always return TRUE**,

```
    {% if page.highlighted %}
      {% block highlighted %}
        <div class="highlighted">{{ page.highlighted }}</div>
      {% endblock %}
    {% endif %}
```

is there any way to check that messages exists in page in drupal 8?

Comment: Just a suggestion...cant we create a custom  variable.... and set it to true or false depending on message block ???

Comment: @ShreyaShetty, that would be difficult, because the page template can't look in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the `page.highlighted` variable contains the block data (`mytheme_messages`) for message display, the block rendering data doesn't contain the messages themselves, so there's no way to check for message existance there.

However, you can inject a custom variable based on the current message queue from [`drupal_get_messages()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_messages/8.2.x).

For example, in your **MYTHEME.theme**:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page() for page.html.twig.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(array &$variables) {
  // Inject a flag based on the current message queue.
  $variables['available_messages'] = !empty(drupal_get_messages(NULL, FALSE));
}
```

And within your **page.html.twig**:

```
{% if available_messages == true %}
   <!-- TODO: Add custom markup when there are messages -->
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 9, use the [Messenger](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Messenger%21Messenger.php/function/Messenger%3A%3Aall/9.0.x) service.

```php
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(array &$variables) {
  $variables['available_messages'] = !empty(\Drupal::messenger()->all());
}
```

Comment: This works great in general. But in my case, it didn't catch some webform validation messages. Maybe because I'm using a webform referenced from a paragraph.